# How to deprecate a single function in a global interface

Tags: apex, deprecation

Can I deprecate a single function from a global interface that has been managed released?

I was using this:

```
global interface MyInterface {
    String getSomeString();

    @deprecated
    Integer getSomeInt();
}
```

but that gives me this error:

```
Save error: expecting right curly bracket, found '@'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation, it says you can deprecate an interface but cannot deprecate each individual methods in interface.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_deprecated.htm

Comment: Right, I got the feeling I was missing something, thanks.